# Eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian for a system consisting of a linear chain of atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I was solving some one-dimensional chain of Rydberg Atoms(in Rydberg Blockade Configuration), which is basically a chain of atoms having alternate Rydberg atoms, there I encountered a certain type of Hamiltonian for Rydberg Blockade Configuration.
$$H = \sum_i^N \left(\Omega\sigma_i^x + \Delta \left(\frac{I+\sigma_i^z}{2}\right) \right) $$
where $\Omega$ and $\Delta$ are some constants representing strengths and $\sigma_i^z$, $\sigma_i^x$ are Pauli matrices.
I want to evaluate the eigenvalues for this Hamiltonian, for that I need to write this in matrix form, so how should I write this Hamiltonian in matrix form?

Comment: Assuming that you have the correct hamiltonian,  there is no coupling between sites so you have a bunch of independent 2-by-2 matrices.